# GRUB sees NVME SSD but Linux does not

Tags: linux, boot, ssd, grub, nvme

The system was working then suddenly freezed and didn't boot up.

After some wrestling with power button it eventually started up but Linux stuck in initramfs cli. Guess this happend in the chroot phase of Linux start up. In grub cli though I can see the 1TB SSD drive and its partitions and I can even ls on them. But Linux does not see the nvme hardware as it is not listed in /dev or lsblk output (not in another live Linux nor its original Linux initramfs environment). So Linux won't boot up. The system was dual boot and Windows also doesn't start up. I should note UEFI detects the hardware. And grub can actually read the drive as it loads Linux kernel and initrd.
My question is that what can be the reason that this ssd is not enumerated by Linux but UEFI detects it? Can it be a hardware failure? Such as where it should respond to PCI bus plug and play messages?
As a side note disabling secure boot didn't fix the main problem. But made it possible to execute commands from grub cli.

Comment: Secure Boot has nothing to do with it, obviously. It seems the hardware failed. Please confirm in UEFI ("BIOS") settings if the drive is still recognized or not. Again, obviously. Make sure to [edit] the question in order to update/improve it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry I edited my post.